# Galaxy tab devices gives error java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

My android app is crashing in galaxy tab but in all mobile devices with Android 4.0 up is working as usual. Below is my error that I copy from Play Store's Crash Report:

## Crash Report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at    kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull.vocabulary_animal.speakWords(vocabulary_animal.java:74)
at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull.vocabulary_animal.access$0(vocabulary_animal.java:72) 
at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull.vocabulary_animal$1.onItemClick(vocabulary_animal.java:66)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1852)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:618)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:123)
at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## My Full Code:

```
package kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;


public class vocabulary_animal extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener{
private AdView adView;
private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.vocabulary_animal);

    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "96ffc9a995384d59");
    AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adsView);
    ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    //check for TTS data
    Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
    checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/TRIFORCE.ttf");
    TextView text_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_title);
    text_title.setTypeface(typeFace);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.animal_gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new Vocabulary_Gride_Adapter_Animal(this));


    final Vocabulary_Gride_Adapter_Animal imageAdapter = new Vocabulary_Gride_Adapter_Animal(this);


    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
            String me = Character.toUpperCase(name.charAt(0)) + name.substring(1);
            speakWords(name);
            Toast.makeText(vocabulary_animal.this, "" + me, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
private void speakWords(String speech) {
    //speak straight away
    tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
        else {
                //no data - install it now
            Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
            installTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installTTSIntent);
        }
    }
}
//setup TTS
@Override
public void onInit(int initStatus) {
        //check for successful instantiation
    if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        if(tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            tts.setPitch((float) 1);
            tts.setSpeechRate(1);
    }
    else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
 }
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
}
}
```

And here my game [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull) in play store, it's working properly with every mobile phone but it's appear error with all galaxy tab with every activity that related to voice.

## Below is another error in play store crashes report with audio also:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at kids.iq.kidsiqpicturesquestionfull.fruit_q_easy_1$4.onClick(fruit_q_easy_1.java:655)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first crash about non initialized tts field. You have initialized link por usage. Now you init it only after activity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
            //the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        }
```

thats why you took that NullPointerException. This isn't vendor or device issue. its only your code.

Comment: Can you help me to insert your code into my code, so, I may easy to understand. I am sorry to disturb you. Appreciate for your kindly help. Thank you sir.